# How to change color when condition is true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, javascript-objects

I want to change the color of the 'left--innerTopBox' whenever the  changes.
I believe im missing a handleChange function and an onChange.

```
import "./App.css";
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [color, setColor] = useState({
    color1: "#fff",
  });
  return (
    <>
      <div className="box--control">
        <div className="big--leftBox">
          left box
          <div className="left--innerTopBox" value={color.color1}>
            color here
          </div>
          <div className="left--innerBottomBox">code here</div>
        </div>

        <div className="big--rightBox">
          right box
          <div className="inputs">
            Color 1
            <input
              type="color"
              style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}
              value={color.color1}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="inputs">
            Color 2<input type="color" style={{ marginLeft: 10 }} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What are you expecting a `value` attribute on a `div` to do, exactly?  As for the functions you believe you're missing... Have you tried to write any function that you believe you need?  What's stopping you?

Comment: hey please add a meaningful title. I also would advice you to read [how to ask good questions on so](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well

Comment: I want the <div className="left--innerTopBox"> to change colors to the which choose from the input. (the div has a css of .left--innerTopBox{
  height: 250px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 3rem;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```html
import "./App.css";
import { useState} from "react";

function App() {
  const [color, setColor] = useState({
    color1: "#fff",
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setColor({ ...color, color1:  e.target.value });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="box--control">
        <div className="big--leftBox">
          left box
          <div
            className="left--innerTopBox"
            style={{ backgroundColor: color.color1 }}
          >
            color here
          </div>
          <div className="left--innerBottomBox">code here</div>
        </div>

        <div className="big--rightBox">
          right box
          <div className="inputs">
            Color 1
            <input
              type="color"
              style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}
              value={color.color1}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="inputs">
            Color 2<input type="color" style={{ marginLeft: 10 }} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

A `<div>` has no `value`:

```
<div className="left--innerTopBox" value={color.color1}>
```

Presumably you meant to use a *`style`*?:

```
<div className="left--innerTopBox" style={{ color: color.color1 }}>
```

Then all you need to do is update the state value to whatever you want.  For example:

```
<input
  type="color"
  style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}
  onChange={e => setColor({ color1: e.target.value })}
/>
```

This can be abstracted into its own function, for example:

```
const handleChange = e => setColor({ color1: e.target.value });
```

and:

```
<input
  type="color"
  style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}
  onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

Note also that this over-writes the entirety of the state.  If you end up with multiple properties in that state object, you can preserve them and update only one:

```
const handleChange = e => setColor({ ...color, color1: e.target.value });
```

Of course this also hard-codes the property name.  You can make that dynamic by giving the input a `name`:

```
<input
  type="color"
  name="color1"
  style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}
  onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

And using that `name` in the function:

```
const handleChange = e => setColor({ ...color, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
```

Which would allow you to re-use the same change handler for multiple inputs that set different properties on the same state object.

Note of course that this will update it *on every change*.  So for example if you type "green" then there will 5 "color" updates:

- `{ color1: 'g' }`
- `{ color1: 'gr' }`
- `{ color1: 'gre' }`
- `{ color1: 'gree' }`
- `{ color1: 'green' }`